# Checking timestamp intervals in matlab

Tags: matlab, timestamp

I was just wondering if there is a way to compare many time stamps to see if any are missing.
At the moment I am looking at 365 days of the year, with everyday 48 readings being taken. (In an excel document) therefore I have over 17000 points to analyse.
At the moment the format of the timestamps are:

```
1/01/2011 12:30 AM
1/01/2011 1:00 AM
1/01/2011 1:30 AM
1/01/2011 2:00 AM
1/01/2011 2:30 AM
```

I need to go through and see if any values are missing every 30min. I have thought of using

```
datenum('')
```

and then trying to compare it, and throw an error when it does not follow the trend and return the previous value. But I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `datenum` and put in one of those exact date-formatted strings that are in the example that you have provided.  If you have time intervals of half an hour, then the difference between successive `datenum` calls should yield the same difference.  For example, let's place your dates into a cell array like so:

```
C = {'1/01/2011 12:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 1:00 AM',
'1/01/2011 1:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 2:00 AM',
'1/01/2011 2:30 AM'};
```

We can take the difference between successive elements using [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html).  How `diff` works, given the i<sup>th</sup> element in an array, the output for the vector at `y_i` given the input value `x_i` is:

```
y_i = x_{i+1} - x_i
```

Therefore, this will return a vector that has its length as one less than the original.  We are basically considering elements from the second element of your dates onwards.  As such, applying `diff` to `datenum` for every element in this cell array, we get:

```
format long
diffs = diff(datenum(C))

diffs =

   0.020833333255723
   0.020833333372138
   0.020833333372138
   0.020833333255723
```

The first 7 significant digits or so matters.  The rest of the digits are due to some precision differences, but let's shelve that for now.  As such, you need to check to see if each element in the difference is about `0.0208333`.  If it isn't, then you're missing an interval.  Let's try fudging a few of the times:

```
C = {'1/01/2011 12:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 1:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 2:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 3:00 AM',
'1/01/2011 4:30 AM'};

format long
diffs = diff(datenum(C))

diffs =

   0.041666666627862
   0.041666666627862
   0.020833333372138
   0.062500000000000
```

Therefore, for the second, third and last element of `C`, we are missing measurements at the half an hour interval.  Specifically, I'm assuming that your units are in times of half an hour.  As such, the smallest possible jump between missing measurements is an hour, and that's a jump between `0.0208` and `0.0416`, so that's about a difference of `0.02`.  As such, we need to find locations in this array where it's bigger than `0.0416`.  To be safe, let's set this to `0.03`.  As such, if you want to do this programatically, you could do this:

```
diffs = diff(datenum(C));
locs = find(diffs > 0.03) + 1;
```

[`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) figures out the locations in a matrix / array which satisfies a particular Boolean condition.  In this case, we want to find locations whose differences are `> 0.03`.  We also offset by `1` because we are looking at the second element like we talked about before.  By doing this with our modified `C` array, we get:

```
locs =

     2
     3
     5
```

This tells us that at locations 2, 3 and 5 for our modified dates array (`C`), we are missing measurements at the half hour mark.

To double check for our first example, if we applied this on the first example when there are no skips, we get the empty array as expected:

```
locs = 

[]
```

---

As a little bonus, we can display at which locations there is an interval missing.  Specifically:

```
missingTimes = C(locs)
```

For our fudged time example, we get:

```
missingTimes = 

    '1/01/2011 1:30 AM'
    '1/01/2011 2:30 AM'
    '1/01/2011 4:30 AM'
```

---

## Edit

From our conversation in the comments back, this messes up as soon as you have a date with no time and just the date.  Specifically, when you call `datenum` with at least one of these in the cell array, we won't get floating point precision anymore.  We will only get whole numbers (for some odd reason... and I can't figure out why.  I should probably make a StackOverflow post about this).  In other words, if we did:

```
C = {'1/01/2011',
'1/01/2011 12:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 1:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 2:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 3:00 AM',
'1/01/2011 4:30 AM'};
```

If we did:

```
diff(datenum(C))
```

We get:

```
ans =

  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
```

---

To get around this, I had to implement my own version of `diff`, and access the elements in the dates array individually.  Therefore, do this instead:

```
format long;
diffs = arrayfun(@(x) datenum(C{x}) - datenum(C{x-1}), (2:numel(C)).');
```

I used [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and I specify an input array that goes from 2 up to as many elements as we have in `C`.  For each element in our output, we take the `datenum` representation of the `i+1`th element and subtract this from our `i`th element.  This essentially implements the `diff` operation manually, and escapes the slight bug when you include a date with no time on it.  I honestly have no idea why all of the decimal points after the whole numbers get removed.... but this works for now.

In any case, we get:

```
diffs =

   0.020833333372138
   0.041666666627862
   0.041666666627862
   0.020833333372138
   0.062500000000000
```

---

## Edit #2

It looks like you're still getting trouble.  Another suggestion that I would make is to find those times that are **missing** the `12:00 AM` time stamp.  We would then find these entries and place the `12:00 AM` time stamp manually.  As such, we can use regular expressions to do that through [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).  Regular expressions try and find where patterns occur in strings.  As such, what we're going to do find those patterns that **don't** contain the time stamp at the end, then use some additional code to insert this time stamp in.  Let's consider a toy example:

```
C = {'1/01/2011',
'1/01/2011 12:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 1:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 2:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 3:00 AM',
'1/01/2011 4:30 AM',
'1/02/2011',
'1/02/2011 12:30 AM',
'1/02/2011 1:30 AM',
'1/02/2011 2:30 AM',
'1/02/2011 3:00 AM',
'1/02/2011 4:30 AM',
'1/03/2011',
'1/03/2011 12:30 AM',
'1/03/2011 1:30 AM',
'1/03/2011 2:30 AM',
'1/03/2011 3:00 AM',
'1/03/2011 4:30 AM'};
```

Here we have various dates and times, with some missing the `12:00 AM` time stamp.  As such, here's how I am going to insert the time stamps in:

```
missingTimeStampsLocs = cellfun(@(x) isempty(regexp(x,'[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AaPp][Mm]')), C);
missingTimeStamps = C(missingTimeStampsLocs);
filledInTimeStamps = cellfun(@(x) [x ' 12:00 AM'], missingTimeStamps, 'uni', 0);
C(missingTimeStampsLocs) = filledInTimeStamps;
```

This looks like some intimidating piece of code, but can certainly be explained.  Let's start with the first line of code.  First, we call `regexp` where it takes in a string we want to look at and then the second parameter is for describing the **pattern** you are looking for.  What I have to do here is I am going to look for all dates that following the following format:

```
 #/##/#### ##:## xx
       OR
##/##/#### ##:## xx
```

`#` denote a number and `x` denotes a character.  We are going to search for all dates that follow this **exact** format.  Any dates that don't follow this format we are going to flag and that means they are missing timestamps.  Take a look at this statement:

```
regexp(x,'[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2} [AaPp][Mm]')
```

What this is saying is that for a string `x`, we are going to look for a string that starts with 1 or 2 numbers, followed by a `/`, followed by exactly 2 numbers, followed by a `/`, followed by exactly 4 numbers, followed by a space, then we will look for either 1 or 2 numbers, followed by a `:`, then exactly 2 numbers, followed by a space, then either `AM` or `PM` and is **case-insensitive**.  This means that the `AM` or `PM` can be either upper or lower case.

What will be returned from `regexp` are the **locations** in your string where this string is found.  In our case, it will either return `1` meaning that we have found this string at the **starting** of it, or **empty** which means that we have not found such a string.  If `regexp` returns empty, then this date has a missing timestamp.  This is why I wrapped this call with [`isempty`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) to check to see if `regexp` returns empty.  I then wrap this call using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) so that we can iterate over all elements in our date cell array.  The output (stored in `missingTimeStampsLocs`) will contain a Boolean array where `1` denotes that the timestamp is missing, and `0` denotes that it isn't missing.

The next line of code then extracts from the original cell array those dates that have missing dates.  I then run `cellfun` one more time to iterate through these cells, and we then concatenate the `12:00 AM` timestamp at the end of each string in this extracted cell array.  Note that I also specify two additional parameters (`'uni'` and `0`) because the output is no longer a single value, but a string instead.  These strings will be placed inside a cell array, which is perfect because they were extract from a cell array anyway.  We didn't have to specify this in the first `cellfun` call as the output is a single value - in that case, it was a Boolean value of `0` or `1`.  Once we are done, we then replace those dates that have the missing timestamps with those that we just filled in with the `12:00 AM` time stamp.  This gets overwritten into `C`.  As such, by running the above code with our `C`, this is what we get:

```
C =  

'1/01/2011 12:00 AM'
'1/01/2011 12:30 AM'
'1/01/2011 1:30 AM'
'1/01/2011 2:30 AM'
'1/01/2011 3:00 AM'
'1/01/2011 4:30 AM'
'1/02/2011 12:00 AM'
'1/02/2011 12:30 AM'
'1/02/2011 1:30 AM'
'1/02/2011 2:30 AM'
'1/02/2011 3:00 AM'
'1/02/2011 4:30 AM'
'1/03/2011 12:00 AM'
'1/03/2011 12:30 AM'
'1/03/2011 1:30 AM'
'1/03/2011 2:30 AM'
'1/03/2011 3:00 AM'
'1/03/2011 4:30 AM'
```

We can then run this through our detection code and see which dates are jumping by a half an hour.

```
diffs = diff(datenum(C));
locs = find(diffs > 0.03) + 1;
missingTimes = C(locs)
```

We thus get:

```
missingTimes = 

'1/01/2011 1:30 AM'
'1/01/2011 2:30 AM'
'1/01/2011 4:30 AM'
'1/02/2011 12:00 AM'
'1/02/2011 1:30 AM'
'1/02/2011 2:30 AM'
'1/02/2011 4:30 AM'
'1/03/2011 12:00 AM'
'1/03/2011 1:30 AM'
'1/03/2011 2:30 AM'
'1/03/2011 4:30 AM'
```

---

I really hope this is the last time I work on this problem (LOL), as I'm quite sure I've covered all contingencies.  I'm also assuming that your dates are formatted in a specific way, and I'm hoping this will solve your problem.  We also don't need to use our custom `diff` function that we wrote, as I am now completing your dates to have the `12:00 AM` timestamp on it.

Good luck!

Comment: shldn't the missingTime be '1/01/2011 1:00 AM',
'1/01/2011 2:00 AM','1/01/2011 3:30 AM',
'1/01/2011 4:00 AM'?

Comment: @lakesh - No.  I've only displayed **where** in the `C` array there are missing times found.  This doesn't find the actual missing times themselves.  That'll be up to the OP to figure out :)

Comment: Thanks heaps for your awesome response! Seems to have solved most of my issues, I just have one more quick question.

If my data started with:
1/01/2011
and then continued on as per usual...
1/01/2011 12:30 AM
1/01/2011 1:00 AM
1/01/2011 1:30 AM
The diff value seems to return 0 for all of them.

Comment: @user3575908 - You sure? I just did `datenum('1/01/2011 12:30 AM') - datenum('1/01/2011')` and I get `0.0208` as expected.  If you omit the time, it assumes midnight.  Can you show me what your data actually looks like at the start?

Comment: I tried that as well and got the same answer as you.

My actual data starts at the 'blank' midnight, so like:
Date/Time
1/01/2011
1/01/2011 12:30 AM
1/01/2011 1:00 AM
1/01/2011 1:30 AM
1/01/2011 2:00 AM
1/01/2011 2:30 AM
1/01/2011 3:00 AM

and then continues on.

Comment: I found the problem. It didn't like the heading Date/Time in it, even when I removed this using code. 
C(1,:) = [];

Comment: @user3575908 - OH yes haha. Yeah `datenum` won't like the heading there.  Did it work?

Comment: Not sure if you have time for one final question but...
Going from the last value of the day, to the next day also picks up a missing value. Trying to think of a way to get round this.

Comment: @user3575908 - Just did a test and it doesn't for me.  The difference between 11:30PM from a previous day and going to 12:00 AM for the next day yields a difference of `0.0208`.  It shouldn't pick up a missing time value because date numbers are linearly increasing with respect to a reference date.  Not sure why that's happening for you.

Comment: It seems that it depends what format yu have dd/mm/yyyy in. Excel has it one way but matlab keeps reading it in another way.

Comment: @user3575908 - Did you figure it out?

Comment: Not yet, its still being temperamental. :/
When I specify the format dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM it doesn't like it when it is missing the midnight one. I'll keep having a muck around. When I copy and paste it in from excel it works, just not importing it using xlsread.

Comment: So when I go >> datenum('1/01/2011', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM') It throws an error instead of defaulting to zero like it should @rayryeng

Comment: @user3575908 - I have one more suggestion.  Any days that have missing times, we will fill it in with `12:00:00 AM` so that this script can work.  I can do that very quickly.  I'll place an edit.

Comment: @user3575908 - I have finished.  I think you should pay me for helping you solve your problem :P  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng You are a legend, I wish I could buy you a beer haha. Thanks once again. My data should now be perfect for analysis.

Comment: @user3575908 haha no worries. This was a very interesting problem to solve. It screws up when there's no timestamp because everything in the cell array must be formatted the same. If we don't then we get that unexpected error you're seeing. In that case, we have to fix your data a bit. Your sentiment about the beer is duly noted and I was kidding about the paying bit ;-) all the best!