# check sequence of minutes matlab

Tags: matlab, sequence

I have a cell array that should contain the time from '00:00:00' to '23:59:00' with 1 minute resolution:

```
time={'00:00:00'
'00:01:00'
'00:02:00'
'00:03:00'
'00:04:00'
'00:05:00'
'00:06:00'
'00:07:00'
'23:59:00'}
```

What is a smart way to check if all the minutes are present in the cell array 'time' and identify the missing ones?

Using the vector in the example I would like a vector containing NaN in correspondence of missing minutes:

```
missing_time={'00:00:00'
'00:01:00'
'00:02:00'
'00:03:00'
'00:04:00'
'00:05:00'
'00:06:00'
'00:07:00'
NaN
NaN
...
'23:59:00'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way to find if there is a missing one. Check the number of elements: `numel(time)` if it is smaller than 60*24 you have missing elements :D

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478989/checking-timestamp-intervals-in-matlab/25479289#25479289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes a solution, which uses setdiff to find the missing times from the given time cell and a all times of that day.

```
% convert to serial datenum
time_serial = datenum(time, 'HH:MM:ss');
dt = 1/(24*60); % 1 min

% full time (1440x1)
time_full = datenum('00:00:00', 'HH:MM:ss'):dt:datenum('23:59:00', 'HH:MM:ss');

% find missing times and replace with NaN
[~, missing_idx] = setdiff(time_full, time_serial);
time_missing = cellstr(datestr(time_full, 'HH:MM:ss'));
time_missing(missing_idx,:) = cellstr(repmat('NaN',length(missing_idx),1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should convert to a serial date number format like this:

`datenum(datevec(time))`

but this is in days so lets convert to minutes:

`datenum(datevec(time))*24*60`

and now `diff` will give the number in minutes between consecutive elements:

`diff(datenum(datevec(time)))`

For your example data this gives us:

```
ans =

   1.0000e+00
   1.0000e+00
   1.0000e+00
   1.0000e+00
   1.0000e+00
   1.0000e+00
   1.0000e+00
   1.4320e+03
```

which implies that the first 7 elements are correct, but then you're missing 1431 minutes (i.e. add 1431 `NaN`s) between element 7 and 8.So let's simplify your example data to work with reasonable numbers so you can see one way to fill in the `NaN`s:

```
time={'00:00:00'
'00:01:00'
'00:02:00'
'00:04:00'
'00:05:00'
'00:06:00'
'00:10:00'}


I = round(cumsum(diff(datenum(datevec({'00:00:00',time{:}}'))*24*60)))+1           %//'

missing_time = cell(11,1);  %// in your actual solution you would replace 11 with 60*24
missing_time(:) = NaN;
missing_time(I) = {time{:}}'         %//'

missing_time = 
{
  [1,1] = 00:00:00
  [2,1] = 00:01:00
  [3,1] = 00:02:00
  [4,1] = NaN
  [5,1] = 00:04:00
  [6,1] = 00:05:00
  [7,1] = 00:06:00
  [8,1] = NaN
  [9,1] = NaN
  [10,1] = NaN
  [11,1] = 00:10:00
}
```

Comment: I suppose a you would want to use a `cumsum` or so to actually get the indices of the relevant values.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin exactly

Comment: @gabboshow I don't think the braces are needed around `NaN`, but I've only tested online in Octave so Matlab could be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some simple steps to achieve what you need:

1. Generate all required times
2. Use `ismember` to see which of them can be found in the actual list
3. Replace the rest with `NaN`